# JavaBDD and CUDD on a 64bit Windows Machine

Tags: java, java-native-interface, cudd

I have troubles getting JavaBDD working on a 64bit (Windows*) Machine with the CUDD (or BuDDy) backend.

I obtained a copy of JavaBDD from [here](https://javabdd.sourceforge.net/installing.html).
It shipps with a number of backend 32bit *.dll*-s, which are useless on a 64bit JVM.
Hence, I tried to compile the CUDD library from the [source (mirror)](https://github.com/ivmai/cudd.git).

I used mingw-64 on an Ubuntu WSL.

```
git clone https://github.com/ivmai/cudd.git .
aclocal
automake
mkdir build
cd build
../configure --enable-shared --enable-dddmp --enable-obj --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=... (local directory)
make
make install
```

As expected, I find the *libcudd-3-0-0-0.dll* in my *--prefix* directory.
I rename the dll to *cudd.dll*, as this is the name, JavaBDD is searching for, and copy it in the right place (e.g. in the directory from which I will run my JAR).

When I was trying to load the dll, that was shipped with JavaBDD, the library could not b loaded at all. Now with the newly compiled library, it apparently loads the lib (`NativeLibraries::findFromPaths(...)` returns a `NativeLibrary`, loaded from the expected path).

Right after that (? at CUDDFactory.registerNatives(), in which I could not step into, or during some unknown static code snippets ?) an `UnsatisfiedLinkageError` is thrown.

```
UnsatisfiedLinkageError {
   DetailMessage: net/sf/javabdd/CUDDFactory.registerNatives()V
}
```

I hope I provided enough detail, that someone may shine light on my mistakes and help me, get this running. If more detail is necessary, feel free to ask.

(* I haven't tried it on other OS)

*I have already consulted ChatGPT on this matter. It was imaginative, but useless.*

---

A small JUnit Test as MVC for the Java Part:

```
    @Test
    public void registerNativeTest() {
        System.loadLibrary("cudd");
        registerNatives();
    }

    private static native void registerNatives();
```

Comment: Random guess: the symbol naming is slightly different between mingw and visual studio. Use dumpbin.exe on the dll and search for registerNatives

Answer (score 1):

> Random guess: the symbol naming is slightly different between mingw and visual studio. Use dumpbin.exe on the dll and search for registerNatives –
> Botje

The random guess was wrong about the reason, but the comment still super helpful:
Comparing the output of `dumpbin /EXPORT` quickly revealed, that the *cudd.dll*, shipped with the JavaBDD library is not of the same source as libcudd.dll.

Instead it is a compilation of specialised JNI interface implementation, that is shipped with the source code of the JavaBDD library.
Unfortunately, the project uses deprecated features of Java 8 in both code an build script, so that it will take some effort to get it running.

Comment: Did you manage to make it work?

Comment: Not yet. Currently I have an exam period, after which I will try to work it out again. Probably I need to ask tons of questions till I succeeded, since I am new to JNI and C++ build compiler suits and build systems. Unless ofc, someone experienced with such matters, is faster and publishes a modernized fork, before I succeed.